They don't have the book? Don't they have the book?
Which sentence with the question word order or with the usual word order should I use in this situation? Do those two questions mean the same thing here or is there some difference in meaning between them?
The situation:
One day a student of mine in my class did not have the textbook. We agreed that she would go to the college bookstore after class to buy the book. After class she went to the bookstore to buy the book and a few minutes later I left and while I was walking to my car, I saw the student leaving the bookstore but she didn't have the book or a bag in her hand so I was thinking that the bookstore had sold out or had run out of the book. But I wasn't 100% sure so I asked her this question:

They don't have the book?
Don't they have the book?

(By some native speaker, I've just been told here that the whole difference just boils down to formal/informal English, but I doubt that since it sometimes might be difficult to look at your own language from the outside)

The statement spoken as a question "They don't have the book?" would mark that this is strongly counter to expectations.

-- I went to the bookstore and but they don't have the book.
-- They don't have the book? But just yesterday I was in the bookshop and there was a big pile of them.  Are you certain you went to the right shop?

You had a strong expectation that the book would be in the shop, but now you are told that it is not. You aren't really asking for information. Mostly you are expressing surprise.
"Don't they have the book?" as a negative question also expresses surprise, but it is phrased a question and is a genuine question which the person should answer.
In your case, you are asking a genuine question, and so "Don't they have the book?" is appropriate.

It's quite interesting that you chose "Don't they have the book?" since this american girl chose otherwise. She used "They don't have the book?" in this case. Is it the difference between American English and British English or something else? (here at 2:05) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N9ekl5NLGs&t=127s&ab_channel=LearnAcademicEnglish

The story starts at 1:25. For your convenience.

By the way, in the same video the woman says <"For example, maybe, for some reason you assume that I don't have kids, so if you ask me "You don't have kids?"..."> For some reason, she used this word order to ask a genuine question. Is it again American/British English thing? (link to the exact moment in the YouTube video): https://youtu.be/4N9ekl5NLGs?t=264

Not really  "You don't have kids" is what you'd say if you assume that I have kids, but you learn that I don't.

Then why did that American woman use "You don't have kids?" as a question that is asked by a person who assumes that you don't have kids? The link to the exact moment in the YouTube video: https://youtu.be/4N9ekl5NLGs?t=264

@IlyaTretyakov - people don't speak like rule-based robot would. Both ways of asking the question are possible, when you do (and when you don't) expect a particular answer.

@MichaelHarvey still, that American woman used the exact opposite logic. She used the usual word order "You don't..." instead of the question word order "Don' you...." and she said that this question follows an assumption that the interlocutor don't have kids (instead of what James K said one comment above). You see? I've come here to learn, to try and understand English logic. But what I see now is that nobody can give a straight answer.

@IlyaTretyakov - 'But what I see now is that nobody can give a straight answer.' - yes. This is not because we are deliberately trying to be awkward, but because native speakers often break, ignore, or do not know about the 'rules' that are taught to learners, especially in informal speech.

I made my answer as straightforward as possible.  But don't try to use "logic"  You need flexibility.  The woman's expression would indicate that this was strongly counter to her expectations.  I disagree with the explanation in the video.  You would use "you don't have kids?"  when you had previously assumed that I do have kids, but you are told that in fact I don't, and you are looking for confirmation.  She is wrong. (is that a "straight" answer for you.??)

But the teaching point she is makeing is not about that.  it is about the fact that "Yes" goes with a positive verb form even when answering a question posed in the negative.  I think she makes a mistake by using the "statement as a question" instead of simply a negative question.
